# How to move all child widgets to another container

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk

I have a gtk widget (from gtk_dialog_new()) which was created in a different function and bunch of widgets added to it. Now I want to reparent all the children of this widget to another container. 
Something like:

```
get_widget_get_all_childrent(list);
//loop over list and reparent all children
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found the answer after a bit of googling.

First I need to get a list of children:

```
GList* list = gtk_container_get_children();

      //then loop over and reparent

     g_object_ref(widget);
     gtk_container_remove(GTK_CONTAINER(old_parent), widget);
     gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(new_parent), widget);
     g_object_unref(widget);
```